# PostgreSQL Group values by category, count and calculate percentage

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a table `moves`.

```
uuid | tag | ...
-----| ----|----
abc  | 520 | ...
def  | 510 | ...
ghi  | 500 | ...
jkl  | 310 | ...
mno  | 200 | ...
```

The `tag` stands for the type of move. We are talking about moves in beach volleyball. The first number, e.g. the 5 from 520, is the category. "Service" in this case. In total I've got six categories:

1. Attack (category 1, e.g. `100`, `110` and `120`)
2. Block (category 2)
3. Dig (category 3)
4. Reception (category 4)
5. Service (category 5)
6. Setting (category 6)

The last number, i.e. the 20 from 520, is the outcome. "Win" in this case. Every category has 3 possible outcomes:

1. Error (`00`)
2. Zero (`10`)
3. Win (`20`)

Here are the tags from the table above

1. 520 - Service Win (which is an Ace)
2. 510 - Service Zero
3. 500 - Service Error
4. 310 - Dig Zero
5. 200 - Block Error

Here is what I'd like to get: Give me the count of errors, zeroes, wins for each category in absolute and relative values.

I tried the following

```
select *,
    (attack_error::float / attacks::float * 100) as attack_error_percentage,
    (attack_zero::float / attacks::float * 100) as attack_zero_percentage,
    (attack_win::float / attacks::float * 100) as attack_win_percentage
    from (
        select
            count(*) filter (where tag = 100) as attack_error,
            count(*) filter (where tag = 110) as attack_zero,
            count(*) filter (where tag = 120) as attack_win,
            count(*) filter (where tag = 100 or tag = 110 or tag = 120) as attacks
        from moves
        where match_uuid = 'd7eea231-a63d-4d73-b48f-5ca8541ec9cf' and set = 1
    )
as attack_stats
```

and got something like this

```
att_error | att_zero | att_win | total | att_error_% | att_zero_% | att_win_%
----------|----------|---------|-------|-------------|------------|----------
1         | 3        | 13      | 17    | 5.88        | 17.65      | 76.47
```

However it does not feel right as I'd have to repeat the queries again and again for all different categories with all their outcomes.

What I'd really like to get is something like this.

```
category | error | zero | win | total | error_% | zero_% | win_%
---------|-------|------|-----|-------|---------|--------|------
1        | 2     | 4    | 6   | 12    | 0.16    | 0.33   | 0.5
2        | 3     | 8    | 13  | 24    | 0.125   | 0.33   | 0.54
3        | ...   | ...  | ... | ...   | ...     | ...    | ...
4        | ...   | ...  | ... | ...   | ...     | ...    | ...
5        | ...   | ...  | ... | ...   | ...     | ...    | ...
6        | ...   | ...  | ... | ...   | ...     | ...    | ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating your *category* column conditionally with `CASE` statement and include it as a `GROUP BY` in the derived table aggregate query

```
select *,
    (error::float / total::float * 100) as error_percentage,
    (zero::float / total::float * 100) as zero_percentage,
    (win::float / total::float * 100) as win_percentage
    from (
        select
            case substring(tag::text, 1, 1)
                 when '1' then 'Attack' 
                 when '2' then 'Block' 
                 when '3' then 'Dig' 
                 when '4' then 'Reception' 
                 when '5' then 'Service' 
                 when '6' then 'Setting' 
            end as category,
            count(*) filter (where tag - round(tag/100, 0)*100 = 0) as error,
            count(*) filter (where tag - round(tag/100, 0)*100 = 10) as zero,
            count(*) filter (where tag - round(tag/100, 0)*100 = 20) as win,
            count(*) filter (where tag - round(tag/100, 0)*100 <= 20) as total
        from moves
        where match_uuid = 'd7eea231-a63d-4d73-b48f-5ca8541ec9cf' and set = 1
        group by
            case substring(tag::text, 1, 1)
                 when '1' then 'Attack' 
                 when '2' then 'Block' 
                 when '3' then 'Dig' 
                 when '4' then 'Reception' 
                 when '5' then 'Service' 
                 when '6' then 'Setting' 
            end
    )
as attack_stats
```

Comment: It kind of works. I get the expected table layout but only the Attack row has results. All the other rows are empty. I suppose it's because we're using the hardcoded attack values (`100`, `110`, `120`). Any idea how to populate the other rows as well?

Comment: I didn't notice but your conditional aggregates only filters on *attack* values: `count(*) filter (where tag = 100)`. I adjusted to accommodate the other levels. I assume values are in 10 increment, 0 / 10 / 20.

Comment: Thank you! Works as expected. One last question. Is it possible to always get 6 rows as a result even when there is a category missing? For example the match has just started and there aren't any blocks (category 2) yet. At the moment I simply get 5 rows. Could I somehow always get all rows with 0 values for missing categories?

Comment: Great! To include missing categories consider `LEFT JOIN` of a Categories table or CTE on this above query joined at *category*. NULLs will show in this setup but can convert to zeros in outer main query.